# Create Empty Directory structure

Tags: windows, dos

I want to create empty directory structure in windows using cmd

any batch file?

can any one help me?

Comment: You mean you have a directory tree and you want to map it with empty folders? How do you have it stored ?

Comment: i want to use it as index in my another pc

Comment: @user664661 you haven't answered either of my questions.

Comment: @Khez : i couldnt understand your question

Comment: md is the command to make a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
echo Enter Source to be copied
set/p "sr=>"
echo Entr Destination
set/p "ds=>"
echo enter foldername in which structure to be created.
set/p "nm=>"
xcopy %sr% %ds%\%nm%\ /S /E /C /T /H
echo structure created succesfully.......
```

put in text file and save it as .bat extension